# gen_sctp:open(). returns exception error: bad argument - only for Erlang compiled from sources for Docker Image based on Rocky Linux

Tags: docker, erlang, erlang-otp, sctp

I prepared some time ago **Docker Container** Image based on **CentOS 7.9** with erlang-otp build `22.3.4.11` from sources - https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases/download/OTP-22.3.4.11/otp_src-22.3.4.11.tar.gz. All worked fine - as expected:

```
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.2.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:32:32] [ds:32:32:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.7.2.4  (abort with ^G)
1> gen_sctp:open().
{ok,#Port<0.6>}
2>
```

Now I'm trying to do the same but on **Rocky Linux 8.4/8.5** Docker Image and build the same version - `22.3.4.11` from sources. All were successfully compiled on the same server (as CentOS 7.x based Docker Image) but **sctp does not work** correctly for **Rocky Linux Docker based Image only**.

```
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.2.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:32:32] [ds:32:32:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.7.2.4  (abort with ^G)
1> gen_sctp:open().
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  gen_sctp:open/1
        called as gen_sctp:open([])
2>
```

I trying to test also `22.3.4.23` version and the same error were shown.
I also tried install from Rocky RPM packages `yum install erlang.x86_64` - `22.0.7-1.el8` and all working fine.
I would to use **own compiled version** on Rocky to have easy way to update erlang to newer version.
Please let me know what should I do to fix `exception error: bad argument` for `gen_sctp:open().` for Rocky Linux?

Dockerfile for Rocky Linux 8.5/CentOS 7.9.2009:

```
# For Rocky Linux
FROM rockylinux/rockylinux:8.5
# For CentOS Linux - comment above FROM and uncomment below FROM
# FROM centos:7.9.2009

### Update Image packages
RUN echo 'tsflags=nodocs' >> /etc/yum.conf && \
    yum clean all && \
    yum update -y && \
    yum install -y \
    glibc-langpack-en \
    diffutils \
    findutils \
    wget \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    gcc-c++ \
    autoconf.noarch \
    ncurses-devel \
    make \
    unixODBC-devel.x86_64 \
    lksctp-tools \
    lksctp-tools-devel

ENV ERLANGOTP_VERSION 22.3.4.11
ENV ERLANGOTP_DIR_NAME otp_src_${ERLANGOTP_VERSION}
ENV ERLANGOTP_ARCHIVE otp_src_${ERLANGOTP_VERSION}.tar.gz
RUN wget https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases/download/OTP-${ERLANGOTP_VERSION}/${ERLANGOTP_ARCHIVE} -O /tmp/${ERLANGOTP_ARCHIVE} && \
    tar -xf /tmp/${ERLANGOTP_ARCHIVE} -C /tmp && \
    pushd /tmp/${ERLANGOTP_DIR_NAME} && \
    ./otp_build autoconf && \
    ./configure \
        --enable-sctp \
        --prefix=/usr/local \
        && \
    make -j $(nproc) -l $(nproc) && \
    make install && \
    rm -rf /tmp/${ERLANGOTP_DIR_NAME} /tmp/${ERLANGOTP_ARCHIVE}
```

Docker build command:
`docker build -t erltest:1.0.0 .`

Docker run command for tests:
`docker run -it --rm erltest:1.0.0 bash`
`erl`
`gen_sctp:open().`

SCTP Configuration results for CentOS 7.9/Rocky Linux 8.5 Docker Image (in comment found difference for sctp):

```
checking for netpacket/packet.h... yes
checking for netinet/sctp.h... yes
checking for sctp_bindx... no
checking for sctp_peeloff... no
checking for sctp_getladdrs... no
checking for sctp_freeladdrs... no
checking for sctp_getpaddrs... no
checking for sctp_freepaddrs... no
checking whether SCTP_UNORDERED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_ADDR_OVER is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_ABORT is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_EOF is declared... yes

# for CentOS 7.x - below:
checking whether SCTP_SENDALL is declared... yes
# for Rocky Linux - below:
checking whether SCTP_SENDALL is declared... no

checking whether SCTP_ADDR_CONFIRMED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_DELAYED_ACK_TIME is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_EMPTY is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_UNCONFIRMED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTP_CLOSED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_IDLE is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_BOUND is declared... no
checking whether SCTPS_BOUND is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_LISTEN is declared... no
checking whether SCTPS_LISTEN is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_COOKIE_WAIT is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_COOKIE_WAIT is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_COOKIE_ECHOED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_COOKIE_ECHOED is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_ESTABLISHED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_ESTABLISHED is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_SHUTDOWN_PENDING is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_SHUTDOWN_PENDING is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_SHUTDOWN_SENT is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_SHUTDOWN_SENT is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_SHUTDOWN_RECEIVED is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_SHUTDOWN_RECEIVED is declared... no
checking whether SCTP_SHUTDOWN_ACK_SENT is declared... yes
checking whether SCTPS_SHUTDOWN_ACK_SENT is declared... no
checking for struct sctp_paddrparams.spp_pathmtu... yes
checking for struct sctp_paddrparams.spp_sackdelay... yes
checking for struct sctp_paddrparams.spp_flags... yes
checking for struct sctp_remote_error.sre_data... yes
checking for struct sctp_send_failed.ssf_data... yes
checking for struct sctp_event_subscribe.sctp_authentication_event... yes
checking for struct sctp_event_subscribe.sctp_sender_dry_event... yes
checking for sched.h... (cached) yes
...
checking ERTS version... 10.7.2.4
checking OTP release... 22
checking OTP version... 22.3.4.11
```

Comment: If you run `netstat -s`, does it show an SCTP section? If not, does `modprobe sctp` fix it?

Comment: `netstat -s` showing SCTP section for CentOS docker image run and RockyLinux too. sctp module is loaded by default in host system `lsmod |grep sctp`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested everything again for kernel `4.19.x` and `5.15.5` and notice below things:

1. Red Hat 7.x machine running on `kernel 4.19.x`:

- `CentOS 7.9` based Docker Image with erlang-otp build `22.3.4.11` from sources - **work correctly** (`{ok,#Port<0.6>}`)
- `Rocky Linux 8.5` based Docker Image with erlang-otp build `22.3.4.11` from sources - **does not work** (`** exception error: bad argument`)

2. The same Red Hat 7.x machine but running on `kernel 5.15.5`:

- `CentOS 7.9` based Docker Image with erlang-otp build `22.3.4.11` from sources - **work correctly** (`{ok,#Port<0.6>}`)
- `Rocky Linux 8.5` based Docker Image with erlang-otp build `22.3.4.11` from sources - **work correctly** (`{ok,#Port<0.6>}`)

It looks that Docker Image created based on `Rocky Linux 8.5` likes modern kernels.
Older `4.19.x` kernel cause issue but newer `5.15.5` kernel works as expected with the same `Rocky Linux 8.5` based Docker Image - I don't know why it fixes problem.

BTW. Default `Rocky Linux 8.5` kernel is `4.18.0`.